# how to define a variable in linker script that's aligned upward to a 4 byte boundary?

Tags: c, linker-scripts

I was trying to learn how to write a linker script from [this tutorial](https://users.informatik.haw-hamburg.de/%7Ekrabat/FH-Labor/gnupro/5_GNUPro_Utilities/c_Using_LD/ldLinker_scripts.html#Concepts) till I came to a section called `Assigning values to symbols`, they gave this example:

```
floating_point = 0;
SECTIONS
{
   .text :
         {
           *(.text)
           _etext = .;
         }
   _bdata = (. + 3) & ~ 4;
   .data : { *(.data) }
}
```

and further, they add the explanation:

> In the previous example, the `floating_point` symbol will be defined
> as zero. The `_etext` symbol will be defined as the address
> following the last `.text` input section. The symbol `_bdata` will
> be defined as the address following the `.text` output section
> aligned upward to a 4 byte boundary.

my problem is in the sentence where they stated:

> The symbol `_bdata` will
> be defined as the address following the `.text` output section
> aligned upward to a 4 byte boundary.

I really don't get it, for example, assume the address after `.text` is `1327` in decimal, so `.=1327`, so `.+3` will be equivalent to `1331` in decimal which is in binary equals `0101 0011 0011`
and `~ 4` evaluates to `1111 1111 1011` in binary

so `(.+3) & ~4` will be:

```
0101 0011 0011
&
1111 1111 1011
--------------
1111 0011 0011
```

so `1111 0011 0011` is `1331` in decimal and `1331/4 = 332.75` so it's aligned upward to a 4 byte boundary.

is there anything that I am missing or did I misunderstand the explanation?